# How to implement in-game currency with Google's In-app Billing Version 3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, billing, android-billing

Like the title says, how should I implement a currency system with Google's latest in-app billing v3.

The basics: 
I have currency. 
This currency is earned or purchased.

Currency is given to players periodically.

Currency can be purchased in lots (1,5,10,20,50,100) or atleast that is what I wanted.

Google Play v3 forces you to store ownership details of consumable items on their servers.

You can not purchase the same item over until it is consumed first, removed from ownership according to google, and therefore not possessed in your game any more.

This presents some really painful problems to resolve... if I am understanding this correctly.

Do you make a ton of "duplicate" store items to handle the players ability to make multiple purchases of the same item should he want to restock? Can you make free items that are tracked?

What if the player buys a 100 pack, uses 99. Then uninstalls and moves to another device? He'll get all 100 back. How do you handle that?

So how should I manage purchased currency? Can anyone suggest any decent strategies to handle this?

Thanks,
Gullie

Answer (score 1):

By just using inApp Billing api you can't restore consumable items , which seems logical (you cannot restore something that doesn't exist). You only can restore an item which has not been consumed because of `getPurchases()`.   If you want to be able to restore consummable, you need to handle that part in your app and with a server which gonna track who buy what and who use what.

In fact you're not restoring the purchase but the state that the purchase changed : If an user buy 100 golds , when he move to an other phone , he want to get back the extra gold , not the purchase.

After each action your app should send the user status to the server (currency amount , level, item purchased / used ...) and get everything back on startup.

Be aware that you communication between the app and the server must be secured if you want to prevent cheaters.

With inApp v3 you cannot buy an other item until the previous one has been consumed. So if the user buy 100 gold , he used 99. The last one can be restored if he haven't consumed it : http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getPurchases

Comment: In v3, there are no "consumable items" any more, only "managed products". They are all tracked. You can't rebuy an item without first telling Google that it was consumed.  http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume

Comment: Yes but you still consume your product (once consumed you should not restore it). That why if you want user to be able to switch device without loosing anything , you have to implement a "cloud" storage of user status.

Comment: So... basically, you buy the item through the store and then immediately tell Google it was consumed even though the currency has yet to be spent in game?? This method is ok with google?

Comment: Yes basically if your user buy 50 credits : you send a consumption request and on the response you add those credits to the user's "purse". That's why you need to keep track of the user's money amount , to be able to restore it on other devices.

Comment: What if I don't have a server side implementation to store player data yet, will this consumable currency get me rejected upon submission???

Comment: If your user change his phone , you won't be able to restore the purchase for which you sent a consumption request. So he will start from scratch and can't reuse previous purchase (consumed).

Comment: What if I don't have a server side implementation to store player data yet, will this consumable currency get me rejected upon submission if I have no method of storing it across devices?

Comment: I think what @grunk is saying (correct me if I'm wrong) is that you need to keep track of the user purse on your own server. And you need to check your user's purse on your server to correctly update the amount of currency they have. The Google bit is just used to deal with payments, so yes, once a user has purchased say 10 of your currency then you need to update your server for that user and then send Google a spent notification...