# "Best" way to implement in-app currency across devices

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, in-app-billing, google-play-games

**Background**

I've written a game which I wish to run on multiple devices (tablets, phones, etc.). I've implemented an in-app currency, and have come to the stage where I need to store currency in the cloud so it can be accessed across devices and I can deal with conflicts etc.

I would like to go for the easiest option which, to me at least, means using some kind of available API provided, say, by Google, and not using my own server. I've come across the following possibilities:

1. Google AppState API (now deprecated)
2. Google Saved Games API
3. Google Drive API
4. Google Cloud Platform.

(1) is now deprecated and developers are directed to use the Saved Games API instead.

(2) actually seems to be a great solution because it deals with game Achievements, Leaderboards, and storage of custom data (such as in app currency). However, I see a problem with this in that in the Play Games App, there is an option to **delete** the player's profile, which would also delete in-game currency ! So, while (2) seems great, there is the possibility that currency data could be potentially deleted. Maybe this could be put in ther T&C's, something like "if you delete your profile you will lose any unspent currency and any purchased items"...

(3) Using the Drive API seems like an option, but then after reading online there seems to be many problems such as duplicate file names, potential for user to delete files, etc.

(4) I'm not sure about this option, but it looks like I may have to pay?

There also seems to be [these deprecation schedules](https://cloud.google.com/terms/deprecation) on some API's too.

**My question**

So faced with these (and possibly other not listed) options, what is a good solution to achieve cloud based in app currency? I am trying to avoid having my own server which records each user's currency/data, but maybe that's the only good solution? I want to try to reduce the ability to cheat the system.

**Additional thoughts**

I could use a Google Saved Games API **and** Saved Preferences (stored on the device) approach. I would update both Saved Preferences and Google Saved Games. I could keep both data storage methods synchronized, and if the Saved Games data did not match the Saved Preferences, then merge the Saved Prefs with the Saved Games data (e.g. set Saved Games and Saved Prefs to the maximum currency of either). This would enable me to keep a backup of currency on the device in case the user ever deleted their Saved Games profile. This would fail, however, if the user deleted their Saved Games profile, and removed the app from all devices... so many options...

**Related/Interesting posts**

[Ricket's answer here is interesting.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38633/saving-virtual-goods-balance-in-android-game)

**Possible Compromise Solution**

Due to the constraints imposed by the IAB systems and the API's available, I think I'm going to settle for this: use managed items for permanent purchases, e.g. different level themes, obtaining new characters, etc. That way these will always be available no matter what happens. Once they are purchased they are purchased forever, i.e. I will never consume these items. Have a separate virtual money (gem) system with a maximum of 100 gems say, which I keep track of through Saved Games. That way I get leaderboard/achievements too. If the player deletes their profile, that's their problem, but at least the core managed items will persist. Hopefully T&C's will cover the potential gem loss, and the maximum of 100 gems will hopefully help reduce any fall out.

Comment: It's it really surprising to you that you need to pay to have your server run in the cloud, available all across the globe with almost perfect uptime and not having to care about hardware and datacenters at all?

Comment: Having said that is there any reason you don't seem to want to implement a backend to your game? I am not really sure how your game can work without one and if you already have one then why not store your ingame currency and items there?

Comment: No, it's not surprising at all.

Comment: I don't have a server, and I'd have to learn to code one up ! The Google Drive and Saved Games API's can be used for my purposes, but both run the risk of being disconnected from my app, which means the data can be lost. The key piece of data I'm interested in is the player's current currency count. I guess a dedicated server is the only way to deal with this as any API connecting to a user's data storage area must let the user delete "their" data somewhere!

Comment: Having a dedicated server is the only way here. Everything else would just be a inferior workaround. You should start to implement your backend right now. You can't just add it later on unless you want to waste a lot of your time. Just be sure to follow the best practices when it comes to security.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I think that's what I will start to do. Although I'm not sure where to begin. REST-ful web service springs to mind? I'm guessing I would communicate with my server using PUT/GET, or maybe accessing a server-side SQL database... so many options in my mind I need to read up on this stuff... I'm not familiar with server/client network programming, although I have implement Android Java code before to PUT and GET from a RESTful API. By the way, my game is only single player not MMO, so there's no virtual economy to speak of.

Comment: In the end I wrote my own server back end in PHP. One piece of advice is that if you're looking to scale easily to choose Cloud VPS over a standard web host. There are plenty of inexpensive Cloud VPS providers out there. Luckily I did my research first, I reckon it could be quite easy to choose a bad CVPS provider and rack up big bills.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to checkout [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/features) one of its features is a real time database.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try [Implementing In-app Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html). As mentioned in the documentation:

> In-app Billing on Google Play provides a straightforward, simple interface for sending In-app Billing requests and managing In-app Billing transactions using Google Play.

Since, as you've also mentioned that you are trying to avoid having your own server to record your user's currency/data, it will be within your advantage. Here are a few advantages given in the documentation:

- **In-app billing relies on the Google Play application**, which handles all communication between your application and the Google Play server. You just need to make your application request the proper permission to be able to use the Google Play application.
- You can use the In-app Billing Version 3 API to track the ownership of purchased in-app products in Google Play.
- You even have the option to secure your application because Google Play signs the JSON string that contains the response data for a purchase order to help ensure the integrity of the transaction information that is sent to your application.

Now, if you so decide to use in-app billing, may I suggest to please go through the given documentation and do take note of the important notes, cautions/warning and recommendations. I would also suggest that you read the [In-app Billing Overview](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html) to familiarize yourself with concepts that will make it easier for you to implement In-app Billing.

Lastly, you may also add [Security and Design](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html) as one of your references for more information about best practices for security and design. The suggestion in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382763/how-to-implement-in-game-currency-with-googles-in-app-billing-version-3) might also help.

Comment: Hi Teyam, thanks for the answer. I have already implemented in-app billing. However, once a player has purchased currency (10, 50, 100 gems, etc), then I need to be able to keep track of the currency as it is spent in game. This is what I am trying to achieve, and is probably why I need a server to do this. Google's IAB system does not currently allow to track how many gems remain once a managed purchase of 100 gems has been made, for example. Given Xavier's comments I wrote a RESTful PHP web service last night which is working, which should help me achieve my goal.